# ExtJS layout issue with hbox and nested items

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have an existing layout like the following where each box is a D3 chart

```
================================
           |
 box 1     |    box 2
           |
           |
================================
           |
           |
 box 3     |   box 4
           |
           |
```

I would like to arrange box 1 so it has 2 buttons above it for switching charts.

```
=============
button|button
 box 1
```

So the full layout would be like

```
================================
               |
 button|button |    box 2
 box 1         |
               |
================================
               |
               |
 box 3         |    box 4
               |
               |
```

The code for the existing layout is below

```
{
  xtype: 'container',
  layout: {
    type: 'hbox',
    align: 'stretch',
    pack: 'start'
  },
  flex: 1,
  padding: 5,
  defaults: {
    viewId: me.viewId,
    frame: true,
    height: 350,
    cls: 'app-panel'
  },
  items: [
     {xtype:'panel', itemId: 'box-1'},
     {xtype:'panel', itemId: 'box-2'},
     {xtype:'panel', itemId: 'box-3'},
     {xtype:'panel', itemId: 'box-4'}
]}
```

So i need to replace the first panel (itemId: 'box-1') with some sort of parent panel or container. I am having difficulty achieving this. How can i get the 2 buttons to sit inline and then have the box underneath it ?

Comment: You started with your layout but seem to have stopped once getting the 4 panels. I've answered the question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution of many possible to arrive at the layout you are asking how to do.

Can be seen working on this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/31s7)

```
let cnt = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
        items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch',
                pack: 'start'
            },
            padding: 10,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                width: '100%',
                margin: '0 0 10 0',
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    align: 'fit',
                    pack: 'start'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    flex: 1,
                    height: 250,
                    title: 'Panel 1',
                    itemId: 'box-1',
                    bodyPadding: 10,
                    margin: '0 10 0 0',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Button 1'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Button 2'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        width: '100%',
                        height: 150,
                        style: {
                            border: '1px solid #000'
                        },
                    }]
                }, {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    flex: 1,
                    height: 250,
                    title: 'Panel 2',
                    itemId: 'box-2',
                    bodyPadding: 10,
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'container',
                        width: '100%',
                        height: 150,
                        style: {
                            border: '1px solid #000'
                        },
                    }]
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'container',
                width: '100%',
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    align: 'fit',
                    pack: 'start'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    flex: 1,
                    height: 225,
                    title: 'Panel 3',
                    itemId: 'box-3',
                    bodyPadding: 10,
                    margin: '0 10 0 0',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'container',
                        width: '100%',
                        height: 150,
                        style: {
                            border: '1px solid #000'
                        },
                    }]
                }, {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    flex: 1,
                    height: 225,
                    title: 'Panel 4',
                    itemId: 'box-4',
                    bodyPadding: 10,
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'container',
                        width: '100%',
                        height: 150,
                        style: {
                            border: '1px solid #000'
                        },
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    })
```

Comment: Please do not add a single container to a panel. You might also do the stuff inside the panel. ==> e.g. box-4 would not need another container inside.

Comment: @Dinkheller Those containers were layout reference only to illustrate how it was working.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the first layout alreay in place you can use the following:

```
{
    xtype:'panel',
    itemId: 'box-1',
    tbar:[{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'switch A'
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'switch B'
    }]
}
```

Other options are `dockedItems` and `buttons` (though these go to the bottom like `fbar`).

Comment: Thanks, i am now using the tbar config along with the layout below and it's working well.